# use appsetting key in mvc view with string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to assign appsetting key value + string in MVC view.

I tried `@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"].ToString()+"Custom/CustomerProfile.aspx"`, but did not worked.

```
   <a href="here..." id="doneLink" class="btn btn-primary">Done</a>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to use that concatenated string in the href attribute of the <a> tag?

Comment: BTW, you link ends in .aspx, so it seems like you are not using Razor. Is that right?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it, assuming you want to use that string in your href attribute of your link:

```
@{
  var href = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"].ToString() + "Custom/CustomerProfile.aspx";
}

<a href="@href" id="doneLink" class="btn btn-primary">Done</a>
```

But, it looks like you are not using Razor, because your link ends in .aspx, not .cshtml. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Put parenthesis around the code to make it an explicit expression:

```
<a href="@(
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"].ToString()+"Custom/CustomerProfile.aspx"
)" id="doneLink" class="btn btn-primary">Done</a>
```

---

Below is a handy quick reference from Phil Haack:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. What specific error are you getting?

```
<a href="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]" />
```